# typedef with pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

I am beginner in C programming and I am studying on Linked Lists.
I am trying to create a Linked List which is gonna display the letters in correct order. The program enables the user to insert a character in the list in alphabetical order or to delete a character from the list. 
So, I follow an example to a point but there is something that I cannot understand.

Here is the first part of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode {
    char data;
    struct listNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct listNode ListNode;
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

After that part, program starts with the function prototype.
I know the usage of `typedef` in the  second line from the bottom.
But what I don't know is, the last line of the code which contains:

```
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

What does that mean?

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) for a strong suggestion that the last line is not beneficial.  At least in your case it clearly includes the `Ptr` in the name, but `*` is as clear as `Ptr` too.

Comment: I always wounder what would it be good for the suffix/prefix a typename with `Ptr` or similar instead of just putting the `*` in front of the typename. The latter is much more explicit and pollutes namespace less, if you would use this consequently (and if not, what would it be good for anyway?).

Comment: @Olaf I guess we had a similar discussion just a few days ago, and there's *one* possible good use for `typedef`ing a pointer, that is when client code gets it as an *opaque handle* and really shouldn't know it *is* a pointer. (e.g. because it could change to an `int` in a later version without introducing breaking changes in the API) This, of course, is a corner case and of course you **wouldn't** use a `Ptr` suffix then ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: [History repeating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzLT6_TQmq8). It comes up ever few weeks here. But I'm actually against such pointers, too. Note this does not include opaque/`typedef`ed `struct`s , which is very useful.

Comment: @Olaf like this song, long time ago ... still I'm not strictly against that, there ARE situations where you need an *opaque handle* and making it a pointer *could* be an *implementation detail*. But in the general case, `typedef`ing pointers really is a no-no :)

Comment: @Olaf as an example coming to mind right now: consider `va_list`. There are architectures where `va_list` being a pointer is the straight forward choice :) Still you don't want client code to rely on that.

Comment: In general (maybe I should start some code blog :o) ... If your reason to `typedef` a pointer is a good application of the *information hiding principle*, **then** do it. In the majority of cases (appending something like `Ptr` to the name is a clear sign of "smell"), it's just bad ....

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `va_list` is a very special case, as it is not necessarily just a pointer. So, yes, that might be a valid application: if the type is not necessarily a pointer, but we are talking about typedefing explicitly pointers. A counter-example: `FILE` which is only passed by pointers in user code, so could well be a `typedef FILE *`.."appending something like Ptr to the name is a clear sign of "smell"" let's leave it at that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92587/discussion-between-felix-palmen-and-olaf).

Comment: @FelixPalmen: No time now. It will eventually pop up again;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short version:

```
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

defines `ListeNodePtr` as a *pointer to ListNode*.

You may wonder why the asterisk is "sticking" to `ListNodePtr` here. That's because in C declarations, being a pointer is considered a type modifier, so in a declaration, it's part of the *declarator* (the identifier of the variable or `typedef`'d type).(*) This is relevant as soon as you have multiple declarations in a single line, e.g. the following:

```
int *a, b;
```

would define a *pointer to int* `a` and a plain *int* `b`.

You could write it as

```
int* a, b;
```

but that would be *very* confusing, because `b` would still **not** be a pointer.

All that being said, I personally consider it *bad style* to `typedef` a pointer, because as a C programmer, you **know** the meaning of an asterisk. Hiding it behind a `typedef` (and as done here, replacing it by some non-standard suffix like "Ptr") just makes the code harder to read for others.

(*) added footnote here: the reasoning behind this design is that declarations should look the same as usage. `*a` dereferences a pointer, so `*a` should as well *declare* a pointer.

Comment: And to add to your footnote: When the typedef type is a structure type, then `ListNode *ptr` tells you to use `ptr->nextPtr` rather than the stilted but valid `(*ptr).nextPtr`, or in a slightly more complex expression, `ptr->nextPtr->data` instead of `(*(*ptr).nextPtr).data`, etc.  Of course, you'd have checked that `ptr->nextPtr` is not null before trying that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, that's what I'm after with my *opinion* in this answer ... make pointers explicit. Thanks for adding more reasoning to it.

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef struct listNode ListNode;
```

The first line means `ListNode` will represent `struct listNode`.

```
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;
```

The second line means `ListNodePtr` will represent `ListNode *` which is a pointer to `ListNode`.

Answer (score 2):

A `ListNodePtr` holds a pointer to a `ListNode`. So if you unravel the typedefs, it's short for: `struct listNode *`.